# Reading text with Java Scanner next(Pattern pattern)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to use the Scanner class to read a line using the next(Pattern pattern) method to capture the text before the colon and then after the colon so that s1 = textbeforecolon and s2 = textaftercolon.

The line looks like this:

something:somethingelse

Comment: Does it have to specifically use a Pattern object? You can split a string by a regular expression without using the Pattern object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this, depending on specifically what you want.

If you want to split the entire input by colons, then you can use the `useDelimiter()` method, like others have pointed out:

```
// You could also say "scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(":"))", but
// that's the exact same thing as saying "scanner.useDelimiter(":")".
scanner.useDelimiter(":");

// Examines each token one at a time
while (scanner.hasNext())
{
    String token = scanner.next();
    // Do something with token here...
}
```

If you want to split each line by a colon, then it would be much easier to use `String`'s `split()` method:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine())
{
    String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().split(":");
    // The parts array now contains ["something", "somethingelse"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Pattern with scanner.

I've always just changed the delimeter with a string.
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("someFileWithLinesContainingYourExampleText.txt");
Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
s.useDelimiter(":");

while (!s.hasNextLine()) {
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        String text = s.next();
    System.out.println(text);
    }

    s.nextLine();
}
```